# Блок выходит за границы родителя

Tags: html, css, overflow

Делаю сайт с 100% по высоте страницами. Есть 2 вопроса.

1. Как сделать, чтобы .child не выходил за пределы, как по высоте при десктопомном виде, так и по ширине в @media.
2. Как сделать чтобы параграф не выходил за пределы разрешенной высоты?

Думаю есть 1 решение для обоих проблем, но не могу найти.

На данный момент пробовал делать .parent как display: table и .child как display: table-cell, но у меня ничего не вышло. 
UPD: Так же пробовал довабить div как display: table-row между .parent и .child с width: 100% и height: 33%. К сожалению, без должного результата.

**Проблема 1.**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.child-30 {
  min-height: calc(100%/3);
  width: 27%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.child-70 {
  min-height: calc(100%/3);
  width: 67%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .child-30, .child-70 {float: left; width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-30 left"></div>
  <div class="child-70 right"></div>
  <div class="child-70 left"></div>
  <div class="child-30 right"></div>
  <div class="child-30 left"></div>
  <div class="child-70 right"></div>
</div>
```

**Проблема 2.**

[Same problem here](https://jsfiddle.net/e4spkux5/4/)

Comment: к `.parrent` добавьте `overflow-y: scroll;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.parent {
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.child-30 {
  min-height: calc(100%/3);
  width: 27%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.child-70 {
  min-height: calc(100%/3);
  width: 67%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .child-30, .child-70 {float: left; width: 97%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-30 left"></div>
  <div class="child-70 right"></div>
  <div class="child-70 left"></div>
  <div class="child-30 right"></div>
  <div class="child-30 left"></div>
  <div class="child-70 right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, p {
  margin: auto;
}
```